# Why are Centauri women bald-headed, given that the men have peacock hair and do not seem to like baldness?

Tags: babylon-5

As a human, I don't find bald-headed women attractive. I think most human males prefer long-haired women. For Centauri males, if they really find baldness attractive, why do they have peacock hair? It seems the Centauri do not like baldness as well. So, why do they like their females bald?

Comment: It may come as a shock to you that there are different standards of beauty for men and women

Comment: Come to think of it, you sound right :) But bald women is hard for my taste as a human. None of our human races like their women bald.

Comment: Masai women shave their heads bald. Long hair is viewed as a sort of weird western affectation. Borana women shave their heads until wed. There are multiple ethnic groups that view long female hair as unattractive.

Comment: hmm ... maybe shampoos are expensive at where Masai came from. It is more convenient too to go without hair. Lesser maintenance. 
Anyway, the Chinese, Japanese and other Asians love long hair too, though the colour need not be blond.

Comment: Many human men find large breasts attractive in women and yet do not want them for themselves.

Comment: @starpilotsix Can't help but be reminded of "[Guys dream about this sort of thing!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fD7Uah_QUY&t=53)"

Comment: As a human, you don't represent all humans. Simply assuming what you find attractive is what everyone else should find attractive is a bit egocentric, even if you find others who share your tastes. As for the Masai, it's male warriors who wear their hair long.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JMS spoke to this in an interview. Hair length (in men) is viewed as symbolic of power and authority. Women in Centauri society largely spurn these sorts of affectations,  viewing them as a bit silly.

> **What about that hair?**
>
> **JMS**: *Centauri males wear their hair in this fashion, the length of which is determined by the person's status. **Centauri women scorn such symbols of status and go bald except for a knot of hair from the back. (Sort of a peacock approach.)***
>
> *Certainly, you could wear your hair longer than your status permits, but it's like pretending to a status you don't have, which is viewed as pathetic.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Londo Mollari and the Centauri Republic](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/chars/londo.html)</sup></sub>